# npm run <cmd> works slow

Tags: node.js, performance, npm

I used to run various commands via Makefile but for nodejs projects package.json is a more appropriate place for this stuff.

Running commands via npm works great but very slow comparing with a command time execution.

```
$ time ./node_modules/.bin/jshint . && ./node_modules/.bin/jscs .

real    0m0.759s
user    0m0.524s
sys 0m0.085s
No code style errors found.

$ time npm run lint

> @ lint /path/to/project
> jshint . && jscs .

No code style errors found.

real    0m2.246s
user    0m1.637s
sys 0m0.277s
```

It is possible to speed it up?

**upd.** My package.json:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "jscs": "^1.12.0",
    "jshint": "^2.6.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "jshint . && jscs ."
  }
}
```

**upd2.** I measured time in the wrong way. Gant has pointed to it in his comment. Now both times look similar (100ms difference).

```
$ time sh -c './node_modules/.bin/jshint . && ./node_modules/.bin/jscs .'
No code style errors found.

real    0m1.704s
user    0m1.245s
sys 0m0.177s
$ time npm run lint

> @ lint /path/to/project
> jshint . && jscs .

No code style errors found.

real    0m1.822s
user    0m1.621s
sys 0m0.198s
```

Comment: Show the relevant part of your package.json

Comment: Just added it to the question description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't npm's fault, in fact it even measures the time more accurately.

Let's look at what you did.

`time npm run lint` will invoke time, which will then invoke your tasks in order. `time` will stop taking the time needed when `npm` has quit, which it will when your tasks are done running. There is only slight overhead here and the script is working as intended.

`time ./node_modules/.bin/jshint . && ./node_modules/.bin/jscs .` however will invoke `time`, which will invoke `jshint`. Once `jshint` quits, time will quit too and `jscs` will be run without. This is also why in your examples the order of outputs is mixed up.

To get accurate time measurements without npm, try `time sh -c './node_modules/.bin/jshint . && ./node_modules/.bin/jscs .'`

Comment: Oh, it's my fault. Thx. Now I see that npm adds only 100ms delay. It's bearable.