# npm is very slow on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

This question is basically a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661019/npm-run-cmd-works-slow), except that the accepted answer on that question was, "it's not actually slower, you just weren't running the timing command correctly."

In my case, it actually is slower! :)

I'm on Windows 10. Here's the output from PowerShell's Measure-Command (the TotalMilliseconds line represents wall-clock time):

```
PS> Measure-Command {npm --version}

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 1
Milliseconds      : 481
Ticks             : 14815261
TotalDays         : 1.71472928240741E-05
TotalHours        : 0.000411535027777778
TotalMinutes      : 0.0246921016666667
TotalSeconds      : 1.4815261
TotalMilliseconds : 1481.5261
```

A few other numbers, for comparison:

- '{.\node_modules.bin\mocha}': 1300ms
- 'npm run test' (just runs mocha): 3300ms
- `npm help`: 1900ms.
- the node interpreter itself is ok: `node -e 0`: 180ms

It's not just npm that's slow... mocha reports that my tests only take 42ms, but as you can see above, it takes 1300ms for mocha to run those 42ms of tests!

Comment: just a blind shot... try running the shell as admin, maybe consider using a git bash (mingw64) and run npm in that

Comment: Running NPM under Powershell admin console: still slow. Running Windows native node/npm under cygwin bash: still slow. Running linux node/npm under WSL: faster (but still 370ms just to run `--version`. How fast should this be on native linux?) but WSL npm is buggy when running in on the windows filesystem.

Comment: Haven't tried running cygwin node/npm but I'm trying to avoid WSL and cygwin as much as possible - I'm using a windows IDE and my linters, etc all have to be integrated with the windows side...

Comment: in my case even npm -v takes long time

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same trouble. Do you have Symantec Endpoint Protection? Try disabling Application and Device Control in Change Settings > Client Management > General > Enable Application and Device Control.

(You could disable SEP altogether; for me the command is: `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\smc.exe" -stop`.)

If you have some other anti-virus, there's likely a way to disable it as well. Note that closing the app in the Notification area might not stop the virus protection. The problem is likely with any kind of realtime protection that scans a process as it starts.  Since node and git are frequently-invoked short-running processes, this delay is much more noticeable.
In Powershell, I like to measure the performance of git status, both before and after that change: `Measure-Command { git status }`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem long ago, I think it was an extension that I had. I use Visual Studio Code, and when it has no extensions and running bash:

```
//GIT Bash Configuration
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
```

it actually flies, I use both OS, so I can tell the difference. Try using different tools and disabling some.

And if that still doesn't work, check your antivirus, maybe it's slowing down the process?

Answer (score 0):

Been googling this all day, with no luck. Decided to uninstall Java to see what would happen and bingo, solved my problem. I know this is an old thread, but I found myself coming back to it so many times to see if I missed anything.

off topic:
Got to figure out how to get Java working now 
Didn't know about `Measure-Command`, so I'll be using that in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. When I tried to run an application of my job in my home, I realized that in my job's laptop the app starts on 2 minutes but in my personal notebook it tooked 5 minutes or more.

After trying some possible solutions, finally I found the problem was that I installed Git Bash in my D drive partition which is a HDD. When I re-installed in C drive whichs is a SSD then the app started faster. However, I also moved Node.js to C drive to prevent another issues.